# How to upload file with utf-8 symbols in name on jira task as attachment using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, utf-8, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to upload file on jira task as attachment.

for example I am trying to  upload file with the name **"test-äöü.txt"** and it appears on jira like **"test-???.txt"**

Here is my original code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateFactory.getInstance(RestTemplateUtil.getRequestFactory(proxyInfo,useEncryption));
File file = new File(filepath,filename);
MultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
FileSystemResource var = new FileSystemResource(file);
multipartMap.add("file", var);

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>  request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(multipartMap,
                            RestTemplateUtil.buildHttpHeadersForUploadAttachment(jiraUser, jiraPass,useEncryption)

ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange( jiraAdressAttachFile, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

I am setting **"Authorization"** , **"X-Atlassian-Token"** headers in `buildHttpHeadersForUploadAttachment`  metgod and **"Content-Type"** with `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` value

Like I said file goes on jira with name **"test-???.txt"**, than I searched some solutions and tried them but nothing worked for me.
Here is the solutions I tried to solve my problem:

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream()
             .filter(FormHttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)
             .map(FormHttpMessageConverter.class::cast)
             .findFirst()
             .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Failed to find FormHttpMessageConverter"))
             .setMultipartCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Did not work

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream()
             .filter(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)
             .map(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.class::cast)
             .findFirst()
             .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Failed to find AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter"))
             .setMultipartCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Did not work

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new FormHttpMessageConverter() {
                @Override
                protected String getFilename(Object part) {
                    if (part instanceof Resource) {
                        Resource resource = (Resource) part;
                        try {
                            return new String(resource.getFilename().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return null;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            });
```

In this example I tried every possible value of `StandardCharsets` but again nothing worked

I tried this one too

```
FormHttpMessageConverter converter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
            converter.setMultipartCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, converter);
```

and this

```
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();

            StringHttpMessageConverter stringMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteArrayHttpMessageConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
            byteArrayHttpMessageConverter.setDefaultCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            ResourceHttpMessageConverter resourceHttpMessageConverter = new ResourceHttpMessageConverter();
            resourceHttpMessageConverter.setDefaultCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
            
            formHttpMessageConverter.setMultipartCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter allEncompassingConverter = new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter();
            allEncompassingConverter.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            allEncompassingConverter.setMultipartCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            allEncompassingConverter.setPartConverters(Arrays.asList(stringMessageConverter,byteArrayHttpMessageConverter,resourceHttpMessageConverter));


for (Iterator<HttpMessageConverter<?>> iterator = messageConverters.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                HttpMessageConverter conv = iterator.next();
                if (conv instanceof AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
            messageConverters.add(allEncompassingConverter);
            restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

again bad result.

Am I doing something wrong in my original code or in a possible solutions I tried  and described?
or is there something I did not tried and I must do to work my code properly ?

Before posting request, in `File`,  `FileSystemResource` and `MultiValueMap<String, Object>` objects this file has correct name like **"test-äöü.txt"**

update:
issue is with spring boot version less than 2.0